# how I would fix a ReferenceError: Cannot access ‘Client’ before initialization with the code still working

Tags: node.js

I’m getting a “ReferenceError: Cannot access ‘Client’ before initialization, so I was wondering How I would stop that from happening
I’m getting it on this code.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.GUILDS, GatewayIntentBits.GUILDMESSAGES, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

let number = 1958;

Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot is up and running!");
    
    setInterval(function(){
        number += 2;
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get("<DISCORD CHANNEL ID>");
        channel.send(`The product is: ${number}`);
    }, 24000)
});

Client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

My friend tried to help me fix it but to no effect and I am just wondering what am I doing wrong

Comment: Where is `Client` originally defined? Also, you seem to be (trying to) re-define it. That's can't be good.

Comment: You probably meant `const client = new Discord.Client(..`